# How to upgrade automake to 1.16.5?

Tags: automake

In a Ubuntu 20.04 system, I had to upgrade autoconf to 2.71, which then required upgrading automake to 1.16.5. I downloaded automake-1.16_1.16.5-1.3.debian.tar.xz but after uncompressing, it has no 'configure' file. The directory looks like:

```
README.Debian      automake.docs     automake.lintian-overrides  automake.prerm  copyright      patches  tests
automake.dirs      automake.install  automake.postinst           changelog       gbp.conf       rules    upstream
automake.doc-base  automake.links    automake.preinst            control         not-installed  source   watch
```

My question is how to upgrade automake to 1.16.5.

Comment: It looks like you have down loaded *part of* a .deb package - you either need the whole .deb (which I wouldn't recommend, since it may conflict with other packages on your system), or the source distribution from [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/) for example

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed.